# Midori Browser Missing Favicon

Tags: favicon, midori

I'm working on a web application that will run on a device that uses Midori browser in "app mode". The application runs just fine, but I notice that the favicon (a PNG file) does not display -- just a white box as if the favicon was missing completely.

I can find no documentation about what I should expect here. The application (and the favicon) display just fine when I run it in Chrome.

I did see a few older forum posts:

- `When in app or private mode, the Midori window uses the page favicon as the window icon.` [source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/918567)
- `the website's favicon is set as the window icon` [source](https://forum.palemoon.org/viewtopic.php?t=9028)

Other than that, I've seen the list of [bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori?field.searchtext=favicon&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=) that include "favicon" -- but nothing seems to shed any light on this for me. Help?

Comment: What if you use a .ico file instead of a .png file?

Answer (score 1):

When Midori is started from the command line with `--app http://test01-v0-16-attempt-1.test.realfavicongenerator.net/`, it uses a 32x32 PNG icon declared with:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

This page is the test page of [RealFaviconGenerator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/), which means that, when the page contains the package generated by RFG, its 32x32 icon is used (which is a sensible choice for a desktop browser by the way).

So you can:

- Generate your favicon with RFG
- Create a single 32x32 PNG icon manually and declare it.

If this fails, it might be interesting to check your server logs to see if Midori at least try to load your icon.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of RFG.

Comment: So I've been using `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon.png" />` in my HTML, so maybe that line needs an update per your suggestion. I'll try that and let you know (and also check my server logs)